# Complex Integral and Residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Given $t\in[0,1]$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma(t)=4e^{2 i \pi t}$ I need to calculate
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{1}{\sin(z)}
$$

Now $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin(z)}=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$. For $z_0=0$ we get $g(0)\neq 0$ and $f'(0)=1\neq 0$ so we get with the residue theorem and res$_{z_0}:=r_{z_0}$ using
$$
r_{z_0} f=r_{z_0}\frac{g}{h}=r_{z_0}\frac{g(z_0)}{h'(z_0)}
$$
so we get
$$
r_0 \frac{1}{\sin(z)}=\frac{1}{\cos(0)}=\frac{1}{1}
$$
And we would get for the integral in the beginning
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{1}{\sin(z)} = 2 \pi i
$$
since
$$
r_{z_0}:=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_\gamma f(z) dz
$$
Is that ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The poles are at $0, \pi $ and $-\pi$. The residues at these poles  are $1$, $-1$ and $-1$ respectively. So the answer is $2\pi i(1-1-1)=-2\pi i$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct because you must also take into account the residues of $\frac1\sin$ at $\pm\pi$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and taking the time!